# Facebook instant articles RSS feed not working - no articles

Tags: facebook, rss, feed, facebook-instant-articles

So I have been wrestling around with the Facebook instant articles RSS feature for weeks now and I can't get it to work.
I followed the guidelines step by step:
I added the `fb:page` meta tag to our [head](https://hokify.at/):

```
<meta property="fb:pages" content="435703749965571" />
```

I am publishing a rss feed as close to the guidelines as possible here: [hokify.at/fb-articlefeed.rss](https://hokify.at/fb-articlefeed.rss)

I already spoke to the FB business support and so on but no matter what I do, the articles published in the rss feed do not show up in my fb page business backend. there are no errors or anything, it just says "no instant articles created". I am really out of ideas on this. Can anybody help and maybe point me in the right direction what is wrong with my [feed](https://hokify.at/fb-articlefeed.rss)?

Thanks a bunch in advance! best, P

Comment: Is there any error or any problem in the requests?

Comment: What do you mean "in the requests"? There are no real requests I can see, I only enter the url to my rss feed in the facebook business backend and that's it. neither there or in any other instant articles related tab there are any errors. nothing! there are just no articles showing up!

Comment: I assume this functionality is a web one, right? if so, did you try check the "Network" tab and see if the requests or the response of your feed has any state "404, for example"? if you're using code, I suggest you put the code.  Did you check if the rss is a valid one? I'm just trying to understand. `I already spoke to the FB business support and so on` did they answered you?

Comment: Having the same issue here. Would love an answer.

Comment: It makes no sense to close a question like this as "Off topic"!!!!